# How to fix DF-JOIN-002 Error in Azure Data Factory (Only two Join conditions allowed)

Tags: join, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow with a Union on two tables then joining the results of the Union to another table. I keep receiving the following error when I try debugging the pipeline or previewing the data.
DF-JOIN-002 at Join 'Join1'(Line 40/Col 26): Only 2 join condition(s) allowed

I'm basically trying to build a pipeline to automate this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.acct_id, s.Id, Email, FirstName, LastName FROM table_3 s 
INNER JOIN 
( (SELECT acct_id, event_date FROM table_1)
UNION (SELECT acct_id, event_date FROM table_2)) k
ON k.acct_id = s.Archtics_acct_id__c
WHERE event_date = 'xxxx-xx-xx'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyPXj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after some time. I had to delete the Join activity and add it again. It was still linked to another source. Even though only two sources were selected in the join settings